# Want to integrate google recaptcha v2 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, captcha

I want to integrate google Recaptcha V2 but I don't know how can I implement this I know about the server key things the content that I found on the internet is creating an HTML file and load that file with the help of WebView. I want the captcha in the app without using it. `webview`. Can anyone please guide me on this? Thanks in advance.